# Вывести число (деньги) группируя цифры

Tags: python, числа

Как перевести числа допустим у меня есть 1000000 а нужно что бы писало 1.000.000 или 540000 писало 540.000

Comment: связанный вопрос [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320929/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать так:

```
"{:,}".format(value)
```

Comment: а если запятую хочу сделать точкой?

Comment: `"{:,}".format(value).replace(",", ".")`
Навскидку так.

Comment: Благодаррю!!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> value = 540_000
>>> f'{value:,.2f}'
'540,000.00'
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, '')
'en_GB.UTF-8'
>>> locale.currency(value, grouping=True)
'£540,000.00'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')
'ru_RU.UTF-8'
>>> print(locale.currency(value, grouping=True))
540 000.00 руб
```